# Secure authentication between ReactJS and Django

Tags: django, rest, reactjs, authentication

Been reading and watching quite a bit, and asking a lot of questions regarding ReactJS and Django.

This particularly helped me to understand the the flow of data from Django REST Framework to ReactJS and from ReactJS to Django REST Framework.

[Django Forms and Authentication with Front-end Framework (AngularJS/ReactJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992504/django-forms-and-authentication-with-front-end-framework-angularjs-reactjs)

However, the one thing I am trying to understand is authentication to the Django REST Framework. I understand from the documentation that it has built in authentication. Since this is sensitive data, I would obviously want it protected people retrieving it just by going to `http://www.my_site.com/info/api`.

I would need to setup ReactJS to be the only thing that can request data from the API whether that is through a key or username/password credentials. I am just curious how this is handled? Obviously I don't want that hard coded in ReactJS because it will compile with the rest of ReactJS.

Comment: Are your react app and your Django app on the same server?If they are you can just turn off CORS. If they're in different server only allow CORS to the domain of your React app

Comment: Yes, correct they are on the same server. I will have to read up on CORS as I am not familiar with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how I'd approach it: I'd use a [JSON Web Token (JWT)](https://jwt.io/introduction/) for authentication and authorization.

You'd use your back-end to protect **ALL** API requests from **invalid** JWT's *except* for routes where a user won't have a token (ie, registration/log-in pages).

Here's how the flow of the application will go:

1. A new user registers to your app with standard credentials such as email and password.
2. Your back-end will create a new user, sign a new JWT token (usually with the user's ID). You'll probably use a *third-party* library to sign/verify tokens (I don't have experience in the Django community but I am sure a quick Google search will give you answers). Your back-end will send back this token. This is the only time the back-end will receive email, passwords or any other sensitive information on registration.
3. From this point on React will only use this token for authorization. React will save this token somewhere (ie, `localStorage`) and send this token along with the other parts of a request to the API routes you created with your back-end. You'll send this token in the `authorization` headers in the request.
4. Your back-end will validate this token using a *third-party* library. If it's invalid the request stops and an unauthorized error is returned. If it's valid the request continues.

This achieves the following:

1. Your API routes are protected against unauthenticated users
2. Each request to your API is verified for authorized users which protects anyone from requesting any part of your API.
3. You can further solidify this by only allowing requests for users to modify their own data. For example, protect Suzy's profile from being modified by people other than herself by only allowing her token with her ID to modify her account/data.

*Important Note*- Your backend will never save these tokens in storage. It will verify the token on each request. Read more about [JSON Web Tokens (JWT)](https://jwt.io/introduction/) and how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Django Rest Framework has built-in [token authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) and a third party package for [JWT Token Auth](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#json-web-token-authentication).

If you the standard token auth would work for you, then it could be pretty simple with [drf-redux-auth](https://github.com/jamstooks/drf-redux-auth/). If you need JWT for some reason, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014751/secure-authentication-between-reactjs-and-django/42015920#42015920) by Keith above, you could easily fork the above...